# Undefined variable in ansible loop

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that uses variables defined in another yaml file.  In a "shell" block that does not loop, the {{ requests_ssl_cert }} variable expands to it's correct value.  However, the shell block that loops over the tools dictionary, doesn't interpret that variable leading to this error:

```
"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'requests_ssl_cert' is undefined"
```

This is the block in question:

```
- name: Debugging var expansion
  block:
    - shell: |-
        {{ requests_ssl_cert }}
        echo shell with loop
        echo {{ tool.tool_name }}
      loop: "{{ tools }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: tool
    - shell: |-
        {{ requests_ssl_cert }}
        echo Shell with no loop
  vars:
    tools:
      - { tool_name: foo, tool_version: 2.3 }
      - { tool_name: bar, tool_version: 1.1 }
      - { tool_name: baz, tool_version: 1.2 }
```

Without the requests_ssl_cert variable, the loop works just fine.  But I have that variable as well as others that aren't being defined in loops but do in non-loop shell blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is elsewhere and has nothing to do with the loop.
Your example works just fine (I have replaced `shell` by `debug` to print the output and defined properly the `requests_ssl_cert` variable).

```yaml
---
  - name: "Variable in loop"
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local 
    
    vars:
      - requests_ssl_cert: "my cert"
    
    tasks:
    - name: Debugging var expansion
      block:
        - name: shell with loop
          debug:
            msg:
              - "{{ requests_ssl_cert }}"
              - "{{ tool.tool_name }}"
          loop: "{{ tools }}"
          loop_control:
            loop_var: tool
        - name: shell without lopp
          debug:
            msg: "{{ requests_ssl_cert }}"
      vars:
        tools:
          - { tool_name: foo, tool_version: 2.3 }
          - { tool_name: bar, tool_version: 1.1 }
          - { tool_name: baz, tool_version: 1.2 }
```

The output is the expected one.

```bash
PLAY [Variable in loop] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [shell with loop] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'tool_name': 'foo', 'tool_version': 2.3}) => 
  msg:
  - my cert
  - foo
ok: [localhost] => (item={'tool_name': 'bar', 'tool_version': 1.1}) => 
  msg:
  - my cert
  - bar
ok: [localhost] => (item={'tool_name': 'baz', 'tool_version': 1.2}) => 
  msg:
  - my cert
  - baz

TASK [shell without lopp] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: my cert

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```